# Can you use an eventlet pool within another eventlet pool?

Tags: python, celery, gevent, eventlet

I'm using an eventlet celery worker and want to know if it's safe to use a pool of greenthreads inside one of my tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is safe. In unlikely event you experience any issues, please report them here https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/new